# Couples showing affection in public

Tags: halacha, marriage, tznius-modesty

Is there any specific prohibition that forbids showing affection with one's spouse in public? For example kissing on the forehead or holding hands, not more extreme affection actions of course.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18672/759

Comment: A wise woman once told "Those who have it don't show it. And those who show it, don't have it". Amazing line.

Comment: @Anonymous I’d bet all the pennies I could have amassed, from hearing that aphorism, that any sociologist or marriage counselor on top of their game would strongly disagree.

Comment: @oliver: are you a jew?

Comment: @Anonymous Relevance?

Answer (score 11):

The Rama writes ([EH 21:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7592))

> יש אומרים דאין לנהוג אפילו עם אשתו בדברים של חיבה, כגון לעיין ברישיה אם יש לו כינים, בפני אחרים
>   Some say that you shouldn't act with your wife in affectionate matters, such as her checking his head for lice, in front of others.

While some have extended this to prohibit any public indication of her Niddah status (such as via non-affectionate touching) as a formal prohibition, Rav Yehuda Herzl Henkin ([Benei Vanim 1:37:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21282&st=&pgnum=121)) quotes the source of the Rama's citation (the [Nimukei Yosef](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37965&st=&pgnum=602)) who simply states:

> דרך ארץ שאינו ראוי להתנהג עם אשתו
>   כיוצא בדברים אלה בפני אחרים
>   It is *derekh eretz* to not act with his wife in matters such as [her checking his hair for lice] in front of others.

Thus, no formal prohibition is involved. R Henkin writes further that even for a Talmid Chacham who is accustomed to *prishut* such as this, holding hands in public is ok as it is not particularly "affectionate", unlike lice checking was in those days where you would lie in the checker's arms on a bed. Indeed classically, he notes, women wore special clothing to make it obvious to all when they were Niddot.

Obviously, every circumstance and action is different, so consult your rabbi for a particular ruling.

Comment: The *Nimukei Yoseif* ([*Bava Basra* 31 in *dapei haRif*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37965&st=&pgnum=602)) was talking about the story on [*Bava Basra* 58a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=58&format=text) about Avraham resting in Sarah's arms in their burial place in מערת המכפלה. In the story there, Avraham gave permission to be viewed with Sarah since they were no longer alive. See the Taz, for e.g., who distinguishes between that degree of public affection, which he says is forbidden, and checking for lice, which he says is not appropriate (אינו נכון).

Comment: Actually, though [R' Henkin accepts](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21282&st=&pgnum=121) the two categories mentioned in the Taz, he considers hand holding to be not even as affectionate as lice checking (which seems a bit odd to me) - he accepts that avoiding lice checking in public would be a "good practice" (הנהגה טובה) whereas he indicates that, generally speaking, there is no need at all to avoid the hand holding.

Comment: @Fred, then again it is a very common Minhag for husband and wife to walk away from the Chuppah holding hands in full public view, although some don't do it possibly because of the public affection issue (another reason to not do it might be to not embarrass someone who has a Chupas Nida).

Comment: @Fred I don't think he accepts the Taz. He only accepts that there can be levels of affection similar to the Taz, but even the top one is still only Hanhaga Tovah (whatever that means). Re lice checking: it seems he would distinguish a intimate-position lice checking and a perfunctory lice checking in a doctor's office, for instance. Holding hands is in the latter category that even Perushim don't need to worry about, unlike the former category where it is good to be Tzanua about it.

Comment: @Yishai I'm not saying it's wrong to do that; I'm just saying that the distinction between that and checking his wife's hair is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree that he does not necessarily fully agree with the Taz. For example, he refers to avoiding checking hair as a הנהגה טובה, which sounds less severe than the Taz's comment that it is improper to check hair. However, he does accept that there are two categories: 1. שוכב בחיק, which he agrees is actually *assur* in the context of public dancing (between spouses) with extensive bodily contact even on a dance floor (though he does come up with what seems to be a novel idea that שוכב בחיק is otherwise usually only prohibited if there are other people present in a bedroom setting)....

Comment: @DoubleAA 2. Checking hair. He says it is merely a laudable practice to avoid this lesser degree of affectionate contact in public. He classifies mixed dancing with less extensive bodily contact as such. | R' Henkin suggests that holding hands falls into neither of these categories, and that it is totally permitted, because, he maintains that "it is obviously not a marital type of affectionate contact" ("שפשוט שאינו ענין חיבת
 אישות") since even friends may hold hands.