# May husband and wife hug/kiss in front of their children?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, kissing

The Rema in [Even HaEzer (21:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.21.5?vhe=Wikisource_Shulchan_Aruch&lang=bi) writes

> יש אומרים דאין לנהוג אפילו עם אשתו בדברים של חיבה, כגון לעיין ברישיה
> אם יש לו כינים, בפני אחרים - Some say that one should not do
> affectionate things with his wife, such as to inspect her head
> for lice, in front of others.)

This would seem to indicate any relatively intimate act of endearment (hugging/kissing is more intimate than checking for lice) between husband and wife should not be done before other people. Does this include their own immediate family of sons and daughters or are there Poskim who allow spouses to hug/kiss in front of family?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55400/759

Comment: Are you specifically asking according to the position that there is a formal prohibition in public and if this constitutes "public"? According to the position that it's all just about proper manners then the question doesn't seem to start

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, my question is if one's immediate family members are considered part of "בפני אחרים". (Not sure if the issue is "public" as much as one other person seeing the spouses hugging)

Comment: (I don't understand your response.)

Comment: There's a pische tshuvah in yoreh deah Hilchos basar bchalav that can define your bfnei acherim and family members. I believe it's in Siman 88